# jQuery Selector or Code Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a twitter-like app as a learning exercise and have the following at the beginning of my JS file:

```
$(function(){
   setInterval(update, 3000);
   $('.tweet li a.username').on('click', function() {
      alert('hey!');
    });
    $('.showMore').on('click', function() {
      moreIndex += 5;
      update();
    })
  });
```

The alert() is filler for another function that I want to fire when the username is clicked. My generator is creating the following HTML for each tweet:

```
<ul class="tweets">
    <ul class="tweet">
        <li><a class="username" href="#">@jason:</a> tweet text </li><li class="date"> Date </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

This is contained in a div with the class tweetDiv.

I've tried many selectors but am unable to get the alert to fire. Is my selector incorrect? Or is it something else?

Comment: maybe use this instead? `$('.tweetDiv').on('click', 'a.username', ...)` - from the [`.on()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: btw there is no update() function definition. So list the full src. Or create jsfiddle repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is something else. Your selector looks correct.

Most probably your code generates new tweets that don't have bound events. You should better use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) to fix that:

```
$('.tweets').on('click', '.tweet li a.username', function() {
    alert('hey!');
});
```

Here `.tweets` element is supposed to be static and not regenerated dynamically.

Comment: Fastest typer in the damn world, +1

Comment: @tymeJV I am nothing in comparison with [T.J. Crowder](http://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder).

Comment: I'll blame this Surface Pro mini keyboard for now. :D

Comment: This worked. That's a great insight and something about jQuery of which I was completely unaware.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make the wrapper function a self invoking function.

Moreover as you are binding a click even on 'a' tag hence you need to prevent its default behaviour.

Please refer to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid2varun/qK84J/)

JS

```
(function () {
    //setInterval(update, 3000);
    $('.tweet li a.username').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('hey!');
    });
    $('.showMore').on('click', function () {
        moreIndex += 5;
        update();
    })
})();
```

HTML

```
<ul class="tweets">
    <ul class="tweet">
        <li><a class="username" href="#">@jason:</a> tweet text</li>
        <li class="date">Date</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```